# Perspective Transform Acting Strangely in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, gis

I am using the opencv module of Python for a research project. My current goal within this project is to apply a perspective transform that will correct imagery into a bird's eye view. This seems like it should be a very simple problem, but my perspective transform is not working the way that I understood it was meant to.

I eventually got to the point where I was manually editing coordinate values to try and understand why the output was generating so erratically. Upon doing this, I discovered that the software is not at all responding how I believed that it was meant to and I would love an explanation as to where I have something wrong. I have looked up a number of documentation and looked at related projects, and they all seem to work the way that I would expect.

My understanding was that when using a cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() function in conjunction with a cv2.warpPerspective function, you could transform an image to fit the corners of the points that you determine.

Here is my code:

```
    image = cv.imread('Imagery/TEST2.png')
    image_dimensions = image.shape

    input_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, image_dimensions[1]-1], [image_dimensions[0]-1, image_dimensions[1]-1], [image_dimensions[0]-1, 0]])
    output_points = np.float32([[50, 50], [50,150], [150,150], [150,50] ]) * 3
    perspective_matrix = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(input_points, output_points)
    transformed_image = cv.warpPerspective(image, perspective_matrix, (1920, 1080))

    cv.imshow('perspective adjusted image', transformed_image)
```

When I do this, I get a perfect rectangle of my imagery as I would expect.

[image: good transform]

However, if I modify the manual coordinates to shift the upper left corner inward, I get some strange result. I would have expected the three other corners to stay in the same location, and for the top left corner to shift inward (distorting the image accordingly).

```
    output_points = np.float32([[70, 70], [50,150], [150,150], [150,50] ]) * 3
```

[image: bad transform >:(]

Someone please help me understand where I have something wrong. This incredibly simple problem has stumped me for way too long and I am just lost.

Comment: can you print input_points  and output_points? What's the reason for *3 in the the line where you create output_points?

Comment: I added the *3 so the image would be larger and therefore easier to see. From logical inference and testing, this does not distort the result besides making it larger.

Here is the code output for the print statements:

```Input points:  [[   0.    0.]
 [   0. 1919.]
 [1079. 1919.]
 [1079.    0.]]
Output points:  [[210. 210.]
 [150. 450.]
 [450. 450.]
 [450. 150.]]```

Comment: I figured it out, the x and y coordinates were messed up in the input image, I should have implemented this line instead:
`    input_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, image_dimensions[0]-1], [image_dimensions[1]-1, image_dimensions[0]-1], [image_dimensions[1]-1, 0]])`